# Asserting that element is not present still test passes if element is present

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

In Selenium WebDriver+Java+Junit.
I have the following method to assert that element is not present.

```
public boolean AssertDetailNotPresent(){
        if (driver.findElements(linkDetail).size()==0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

I want test to `fail` if it is present, but it passes(

Can anyone help, why it passes? (element is present).

Comment: where is your actual assert?

Comment: How have you ensured that the element is present? Maybe it's not present and the test succeeds for valid reasons (happened to me more than once)

Comment: @Lothar i see it present on webpage and i can find it by xpath that it's present.

Comment: @president OK, then we still need to see that actual `assert` that checks the result of the method you provided. The method itself isn't asserting anything, just returning `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Stultuske I've also tried actual assert: Assert.assertFalse(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Detail']")).isDisplayed());    but test also passes. Although it should fail, since element is present.

Comment: have you debugged your test?

Comment: @Stultuske so I check that the result is false, but result is true since element is present, isn't it supposed to fail? Assert.assertFalse(true) since element is present.

Comment: yes, but have you debugged to verify that that method indeed returns true?

Comment: An element might be present but is not displayed. And: `but result is true since element is present`. Your method is implemented that way that it returns `true` if the element is **not** present.

Comment: many people are frequently confuse by double negatives.  Perhaps you should simply name the function IsDetailPresent, and reverse your returned boolean values, then use Assert.assertFalse(isDetailPresent())

Answer (score 1):

With out any visibility to your *Usecase* it is tough to understand why you are trying to validate a [***False-Positive***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives) scenario. But still to assert that an element as identified by `linkDetail` is present or not you can use the following code block :

```
public boolean AssertDetailNotPresent()
{
        if (driver.findElements(linkDetail).size() > 0) 
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
    }
```

> **Note** : The outcome of this function would depend a lot on the defination of **linkDetail**. If somehow **linkDetail** matches any of the nodes you are bound to get the `return` as **false** else **true** will be returned.

Comment: The terminology here, "Assert...." implies that there will be an assertion raised if the test fails.  I either name this "IsDetailNotPresent", or actually throw the AssertionError.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware You are pretty right. However while answering to OP's question my intention was to provide a solution with minimal change just to preserve OP's innovation without deviating to any other fundamentals e.g.  _methodName()_ or _className_ . Of-coarse _"Assert...." implies that there will be an assertion_

Comment: Makes sense @DebanjanB

Comment: This could be simplified to `return !(driver.findElements(linkDetail).size() > 0)` - Admittedly, this may confuse the issue even more with the whole pass-if-fail nature of the test, but I wanted to throw it out there.